# Nuget Packages do not display on powershell Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, chocolatey

I am new to Windows powershell. I tried some ad-hoc queries to test the package-providers and their respective providers. So far I managed to install Chocolatey and Nuget.

[image: as shown here]

When I try to see the packages available through Nuget, the command does not return anything.

[image]

I tried the same command (find-package -provider) with Chocolatey, and this time the list of packages available was sucessfully displayed.

What's wrong with Nuget?

Answer (score 5):

There is no NuGet option by default when you do a

```
get-packagesource
```

By default PSGallery and Chocolatey have package sources. NuGet doesn't.

To add NuGet as a package source, you need to run the below.

```
register-packagesource -Name NuGet -ProviderName NuGet -location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
```

This will then register the package provider NuGet with a package source. When you run

```
find-package -provider NuGet
```

You should see the list of packages available.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693139/what-is-the-url-for-nuget-gallery-to-access-nuget-org-from-vs2010 discusses other api's to use. I tried the v3 one and it didn't work for me. The v2 worked fine.

It is a bit confusing the way it is implemented.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: The only thing I have to add to this is maybe don't use the Chocolatey prototype provider - wait for the official one to come out. For now it is better to use straight Chocolatey (choco.exe) instead. It even has PowerShell tab completion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TimHaintz ! Unfortunately it didn't work for me :/ The source-package was installed successfully, but the command find-package still doesn't return anything. I am trying to install the sourcepackage using other URLs from the link you provided. I'll keep you posted if it works for me!